# Have to type .php to open menu link

Tags: php

Our site had a link:
http://www.mechanismdigital.com/about

It previously worked fine.

Now it does not, it is required to manually type .php at the end to get to open. For example

http://www.mechanismdigital.com/about.php

and that works.

why is this?

any thoughts?

I do know it's only limited to this one menu.

Comment: If all you're after is a little [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews), `mod_rewrite` is **way** overblown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line of code to your `.htaccess` file...

```
redirect /about /about.php
```

Change `about` and `about.php` accordingly.

Comment: we are creating one now. Originally we did not see a .htaccess file, and it was not hidden. Right now this is working for us, thank you. Since we have live links out there that are not looking for this .htaccess and so eventually we need the creator to tell us how it's done. I can post the results when I find out.

Comment: @user2701729 Sweet - let me know if you have any issues, if not, please accept when you can.

Comment: we think it was previously using something with RewriteCond

Comment: @user2701729 your use case does not fit URL rewriting at all

Comment: I appreciate everyone's input, sure enough there was at some point an htaccess file that was deleted, although it was never initially viewed even though hidden files were visible. Turns out the hidden files were visible but not on the server side so the person missed it. So every time I asked if hidden files were visible the answer was yes, but not on the server side. I should have been more specific when trouble shooting. Sounds like another human error! We are back up and working.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
redirect /about /about.php
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your server config used to have [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) enabled and now it does not. Re-enable it in your Apache server config and you should be good to go.

```
Options MultiViews
```

You should be able to add this to a `.htaccess` file if you can't directly edit the server or virtual host configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Someone probably mis-edited the `.htaccess` file.

That file make possible the redirections, which allows to have the called "nice urls" or "clean urls"

Read the wikipedia article about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL

---

Your contact url: http://www.mechanismdigital.com/contact **was** also broken. (I see you just fix it)

Maybe you had an .htaccess but it was hidden, or the options set on a local php (If you can't alter the /etc/php, well, somehow you had configured the redirection, so is logical to assume an htaccess file or a local php.ini file)

Now, the methods the other answers provide actually work, but require to manually add such lino for each php.

With something like this, you can make it for each php file there:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: that's what we thought, but there was no .htaccess file to begin with

Comment: @user2701729 are you sure? that file is hidden by default. If you guys *really* didn't have the redirection there, is also possible to set it using the php configurations files inside `/etc/`

Comment: we dont have root access to the server so we cant set the /etc/

Comment: @user2701729 I see. But somehow the redireccion was configured. Maybe the sysadmin of the hosting server had a redireccion for php files by default. Or maybe you guys deleted the .htaccess, or have a local php.ini. Whatever the case is, a logical solution is to create an htaccess this time, that redirects every *xxxx* request to *xxxx*.php (as long the file does not exist -ie to no break css, etc) The code I posted does that.

Comment: chris-l you were correct right out of the gate, your first hidden htaccess thought was correct! thanks so much.

Comment: @NateM well, I'm glad I could be helpful :)